# JFRAME filter doesn't work unless I extend/move there frame

Tags: java, user-interface, frame

Can anyone help me with a bug in my code? So I have to make a GUI. I have a filter class given and call those filters upon clicking on the buttons. I added a picture in the center of the panel and each time I click on a filter it should add the filter to the picture. The problem is when I click on the filter it doesn’t add the filter to the label /pic unless I extend the frame or move it.

This is the actionlistener:

```
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {  
    if (e.getSource() == mybutton)  {
        final EdgeDetectFilter myfilter = new EdgeDetectFilter();
        myfilter.filter(thePic);
    } else if (e.getSource() == mybutton2) {
        final EdgeHighlightFilter myfilter = new EdgeHighlightFilter();
        myfilter.filter(thePic);
    } else if (e.getSource() == mybutton3) {
        final FlipHorizontalFilter myfilter = new FlipHorizontalFilter();
        myfilter.filter(thePic);
    } else if (e.getSource() == mybutton3) {
        final FlipHorizontalFilter myfilter = new FlipHorizontalFilter();
        myfilter.filter(thePic);
    } else if (e.getSource() == mybutton4) {
        final FlipVerticalFilter myfilter = new FlipVerticalFilter();
        myfilter.filter(thePic);
    } else if (e.getSource() == mybutton5) {
        final  GrayscaleFilter myfilter = new GrayscaleFilter();
        myfilter.filter(thePic);
    } else if (e.getSource() == mybutton6) {
        final SharpenFilter myfilter = new SharpenFilter();
        myfilter.filter(thePic);
    } else if (e.getSource() == mybutton7) {
        final SoftenFilter myfilter = new SoftenFilter();
        myfilter.filter(thePic);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == mybutton8) {
        final int response = this.fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null); //select file to open       
        if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            final File file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());          
            try {
                thePic = PixelImage.load(file);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

In this part of the actionlistener where the user clicks on open button that opens a directory to choose the file from. Then once the user chooses their file I add the image to the image label as an icon

```
else if (e.getSource() == mybutton8) {
    final int response = this.fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null); //select file to open       
    if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        final File file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());          
        try {
            thePic = PixelImage.load(file);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
            image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(thePic));
            image.repaint();
            myJFrame.pack();  
        }
    }
```

In this part, I am adding the image label to my center panel and added the center panel to the frame

```
this.centerpanel = new JPanel();  
centerpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
image.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
image.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
centerpanel.add(image, BorderLayout.CENTER);
myJFrame.add(centerpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
centerpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,700));
```

[image]

Comment: Swing layout is lazy. If you update a container in some way, you should call revalidate and repaint on that container after you’ve completed the updates

Comment: this didn't work . I tried adding both revalidate and repaint after I added the panel to the frame. i also tried adding it in the actionlistener right after I seticon.

Comment: [mcve] please ...